# Is this list of Notepad++ plugins still accurate?

Tags: notepad++, plugins, web, web-development

I found this list of Notepad++ plugins and there is no date on it.  It mentions sublime text being new, so it may be a little out of date.

http://www.guidingtech.com/31357/notepad-plus-plugins/

Is there a more up to date list?

Answer (score 1):

#### Notepad++ Resources

The most up to date web resource for Notepad++ Plugins is [Plugin Central](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central),
last modified 10 October 2014, at 16:13.

You can also use the [Plugin Manager](http://www.brotherstone.co.uk/npp/pm/) (included with Notepad++), which will notify you of new and updatged plugins.

---

#### Plugins

> From the v3.1, Notepad++ has the extension capacity - the plugin system. Please see Plugins HOWTO to learn how to install a plugin or/and how to develop a plugin.
>
> A [list of plugins](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) is maintained on NpWiki++ and should be complete. You can use this list to add/update your plugins, but it may not be necessary - [Plugin Manager](http://www.brotherstone.co.uk/npp/pm/) plugin is included in Notepad++ release.

Source [Resources](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources.html)

---

#### Plugin Central

> **Directory for Notepad++ plugins**

...

> This page was last modified on 10 October 2014, at 16:13.